# jQuery filter certain ul elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jQuery. I have jQuery code to create a accordion vertical menu bar. The default behavior of the menu bar is to hide all the child elements. The code to accomplish that is as following

```
var menu_ul = $('.menu > li > ul');
menu_ul.hide();
```

I would like save the state of the menu once user has clicked the top level menu and exposed the child options. I am able to add a particular class to the top level ul item to differentiate it from others.

To make this work I have to change the above jQuery code to hide all the ul items except with a particular class. In other words

Hide all the ul elements except where class="show_item"

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to hide all unordered lists, not having the class `show_item`, you could use the [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to accomplish this.

```
$("ul:not(.show_item)").hide();
```

For improved readability, jQuery's documentation suggests you consider the [`.not()` filtering method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$("ul").not(".show_item").hide();
```

Choose your poisin - either will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks works great.. I changed my code to .... $('.menu > li > ul').not('.show_item')